# Setting constrain active in viewDidLoad does not work

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I've noticed that in some cases making constrains active in viewDidLoad does not work. Here's an example, which should work but does not, in my case

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //constrain is not active
    constrain.active = true
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    //constrain is active
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //constrain is not active anymore
}
```

Now there is more code, I am setting few UIImages, UILabels, hiding UIViews but nothing special. It seems I keep having this problem in views with `UIScrollView` and `UIStackView`

By the way, if I call `constrain.active = true` & `view.layoutIfNeeded()` twice everything works fine. Adding sightless delay also fix the problem

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delay(0) {
        self.buttonStackBottomConstrain.active = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Did You try using on ViewDidAppear?

Comment: Yes and it works, but then you can clearly see constrains being modified right in front of you - the views start moving for a second

Comment: Use viewDidLayoutSubviews - that'll be called before the view is displayed, but after it has been sized correctly

Comment: @Xernox The view is not yet visible when `viewDidLoad:` and `viewWillAppear:` are called so putting your code in `viewDidAppear:` works as view is visible at that time. adding delay also works as `viewDidAppear:` is called now either way it's the same thing.

Comment: @GovindKumawat interesting, but does constraint must be visible to modify it's  properties? And the delay in this case does not cause any real delay?

Comment: @Xernox `viewDidAppear:` called just after the view controller’s content view has been added to the app’s view hierarchy. Use this method to trigger any operations that need to occur as soon as the view is presented onscreen. This method simply indicates that the content view has been added to the app’s view hierarchy.

Comment: As content view has been added to the app’s view hierarchy all it's constraint is visible to modify as soon as the view is presented onscreen.

Comment: Yes! delay in any of the lifecycle method will cause an actual delay.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3

Answer (score 0):

The view is not yet visible when `viewDidLoad:` and `viewWillAppear:` are called so putting your code in `viewDidAppear:` works as view is visible at that time. adding delay also works as `viewDidAppear:` is called now either way it's the same thing.

> **viewDidAppear:** called just after the view controller’s content view
>   has been added to the app’s view hierarchy. Use this method to trigger
>   any operations that need to occur as soon as the view is presented
>   onscreen. This method simply indicates that the content view has been
>   added to the app’s view hierarchy.

As content view has been added to the app’s view hierarchy all it's constraint is visible to modify as soon as the view is presented onscreen.

Lifecycle methods runs on the mainThread as do all UIKit interactions. delay in any of the these methods will cause an actual delay.

[Apple Docs View Controller Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3)